# having issue with database table in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am making registration system in laravel. When user inputs data then I store it in database. But when user clicked register button, then it gives me
following error
    Unhandled Exception

```
Message:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'makeitsnappy.user' doesn't exist

SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `aggregate` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = ?

Bindings: array (
  0 => 'asdasd',
)
Location:

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-test/laravel/database/connection.php on line 264
```

When I change the name of the table to "user" then says 
    Unhandled Exception

```
Message:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'makeitsnappy.users' doesn't exist

SQL: INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Bindings: array (
  0 => 'zafar',
  1 => '$2a$08$Xg47q9n65GZSS/l3xgYTyeTC7eICqMimf6KkvdFwSfiOgpFrI0tKe',
  2 => '2013-03-31 09:22:48',
  3 => '2013-03-31 09:22:48',
)
Location:

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-test/laravel/database/connection.php on line 264
```

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE CODE**

Here are my models

user.php

```
class User extends Basemodel {
    public static $table = 'users';

    public static $rules = array(
        'username'=>'required|unique:user|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8'
    );
}
```

Basemodel.php

```
class Basemodel extends Eloquent {
    public static function validate($data) {
        return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
    }
}
```

Here is my users.php controller

```
class Users_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $restful = true;

    public function get_new() {
        return View::make('users.new')->with('title', 'Make it Snappy - Register');
    }

    public function post_create() {
        $validation = User::validate(Input::all());

        if($validation->passes()) {
            User::create(array(
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
                ));

            return Redirect::to_route('home')->with('message', 'Thanks for registring');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to_route('register')->with_errors($validation)->with_input();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the db-schema look like?

Comment: If you're using Eloquent & a non-standard name (or at least a name Laravel can't deal with) set `public static $table = 'tablename';` of your model.

Comment: @Wrikken where do I set $tablename?

Comment: You _probably_ have a `user` class... set it there.

Comment: After adding `public static $table = 'tablename';` still have the same problem.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld How and where can I find db-shcema?

Comment: The name of the table doesn't exist in your database or in a configuration file maybe? I found something that might be of some help: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/329.

Comment: The question is well defined and clear , therefore I give a vote :-)

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment as I missed read your question. To view your database schema you can use tools to connect to your database. I use [sequel pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) on the mac. You can then take a look at the structure of the database table(s)

Answer (score 2):

Having just suffered through this issue, I can tell you exactly what it is.  Double check your "unique:" validation constraint.

Your unique constraint above says "user", so laravel's Validator is looking for that table to do it's validations.

Change that to "users" and voila!  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says there is no table "makeitsnappy" so it seems that this comes from outside the code that you posted here IMO.